# procedure for postgres to create table if not exist

Tags: postgresql, informatica

i want to create table if that doesn't, i tried below code:

```
create or replace function create_table() returns void as
$$
begin
    if not exists(select * 
                  from   pg_tables 
                  where  schemaname = 'Public'
                  and    tablename = 'test') 
    then

        create table test
        (
            the_id int not null,
            name text
        );

    end if;

end;
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

While executing this procedure first time:

```
select creat_table();
```

table gets created but when I execute it again I get the below error:

```
ERROR:  relation "test" already exists
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "create table test
        (
            the_id int not null,
            name text
        )"
PL/pgSQL function create_table() line 8 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "test" already exists
SQL state: 42P07
Context: SQL statement "create table test
        (
            the_id int not null,
            name text
        )"
PL/pgSQL function create_table() line 8 at SQL statement
```

How to achieve this, and also I want to call this procedure from Informatica pre-sql target session property so i want to call procedure with table name as parameter.

Comment: updated my answer again.

Comment: The test doesn't find the table in the schema _public_ because you spelled it _Public_

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)

Looks like this,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
  the_id  int   PRIMARY KEY,
  name    text
);
```

If you must wrap it in a function (don't though, there is no point),

```
CREATE FUNCTION myCreateTable() RETURNS void AS $$
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    the_id  int   PRIMARY KEY,
    name    text
  );
$$ LANGUAGE sql
VOLATILE;
```

If you want that function to accept a name (still wouldn't suggest this),

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myCreateTable(myIdent text) RETURNS void AS $$
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE format(
      '
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (
          the_id  int   PRIMARY KEY,
          name    text
        );
      ',
      myIdent
    );
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE;
```

`[ IF NOT EXISTS ]` has been in PostgreSQL since 9.1

Comment: appreciate your help but if i use
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
  the_id  int   PRIMARY KEY,
  name    text
);

i get error in informatica saying:relation 'tablename' alraedy exists if i execute second time, i dont know if you are aware about informatica tool. so i need to call this operation as stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Error in your code is :

`schemaname = 'Public'`

you need :

`schemaname = 'public'`

But Evan solution is better